# ¿Cómo cambiar variable númerica por texto en Raptor?

Tags: variables, caracteres

Soy nuevo en programación y estoy practicando un poco de logica en Raptor ( perdon si es muy basico). El hecho es que tengo una condicional con variable tipo texto, que quiero adecuar para que cuando el usuario digite un número no de error el programa y se cierre, si no que cambie este valor por texto y continue. He intentado con formulas de comparación pero al tratar de comparar texto con número da error [image: Adjunto imagen del diagrama relacionado]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, con la función `Is_number(variable)` identifica el valor de la variable y con una condicional indique, que si es un valor númerico la variable cambiara a un valor texto que no cumple con la siguiente condición y de esta maera regresa a la asignación de valor.[image: En el circulo rojo se encuentra la función de reconocimiento y cambio de valor]